# Rails using a variable find condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, find, conditional-statements, braintree

I am using Braintree for managing subscriptions in my Rails app.

I have a Subscription model that stores the braintree customer ID and subscription ID.

I want to filter active subscriptions in my Subscription model.  So far I have

```
def find_active_subscriptions
@active_subscriptions = Braintree::Subscription.search do |search|
  search.status.is "Active"
end
```

But now I want to use the subscription IDs in @active_subscriptions to find all of the objects in my local Subscription model with the same subscription IDs and put that into a variable such as @local_active_subscriptions.

The reason I have to do this is to use the local info to access Braintree::Address and only pull active addresses.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One you have the `@active_subscriptions` you can collect all of the ids into an array and pass them right into the `find` method of your local Subscription model. I don't know what attributes you are using here, so I'm just making some guesses:

```
@active_subscription_ids = @active_subscriptions.collect(&:subscription_id)
@local_active_subscriptions = LocalSubscriptionModel.find(@active_subscription_ids)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what Braintree::Subscription.search returns, but if it's something akin to ActiveRecords, could you use something like:

```
@local_active_subscriptions = Subscription.where("id IN(?)", @active_subscriptions.map{ |act_subs| act_subs.id })
```

The .map function should put all the IDs into an array, and then ActiveRecord query would look for all the Subscriptions in your subscriptions table whose ID is in that array.
I'm not certain about mapping on Braintree::Subscriptions; I've never used that.

*Edit*

Like ctcherry said, you can also do the search with find. And I guess collect is good for mapping the ids into an array too. You could also maybe use `@active_subscriptions.map(&:id)`